# Extract url with Regex

Tags: regex

I've a regex to extract an url but sometime it doesn't work.
Here is my regex

```
@"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\. _~%]*)*"
```

And here an url that doesn't work
http://myaddress.domain.com/Knowledge/Legal_Sources/NL/myaddress/Omzendbrieven/repo/machin MÚdecin-conseil Le Ressort.doc

I've this back
http://myaddress.domain.com/Knowledge/Legal_Sources/NL/myaddress/Omzendbrieven/repo/machin%20M

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: The `Ú` char is not matched.

Comment: thanks i added it before the last bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://regexr.com/39p3b)

The regex you are looking for is `@"^(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\w.\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)[/#?].*$"`

Comment: with your solution, i don't have the url when its anywhere in a text